# Java Tetris - iterating through double array

Tags: java, swing

I'm building tetris and am trying to implement a method which iterates through grid[][] of tiles and checks each column per row, starting from the bottom, working its way up (figured it'd be a faster check if I started from the bottom since that's where most rows will need to be cleared).

My understanding of this is- create a double for loop, for each row, check if all columns in that row are full (not null). If they are, I will implement a clear (which is really setting the current row = rows above). For now, I am just trying to output "Full".

My `System.out.println(grid[row][col] + ", " + row + ", " + col);` check correctly shows that it's starting at the bottom row, then iterating each column... but the `if (grid[row][col] != null) {` check doesn't seem to be staying on that row...

```
public void checkBottomFull() {
int columnsFilled = 0;
    //loops through rows only after each column has finished
    for(int row = grid.length-2; row > 0; row--) {
        //loops through all columns per row, then row decrements
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.println(grid[row][col] + ", " + row + ", " + col);       
            if (grid[row][col] != null) {
                columnsFilled++;
                if (columnsFilled == grid.length-1) {
                    System.out.println("full");     
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

---

**EDIT**

```
public void checkBottomFull() {
    for(int row = grid.length-1; row >= 0; row--) {
        //loops through columns of each individual row
        if (isFull(row)) {
            System.out.println("full");
            clearRow(row);      
        }
    }
}

public boolean isFull(int row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < grid[row].length-1; col++) {
         if(grid[row][col] == null) {
             System.out.println(grid[row][col] + "... " + row + ", " + col);
             return false;
         }
    }   
    return true;
}

public void clearRow(int row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < grid[row].length-1; col++) {
        System.out.println("clearing...");
        grid[row][col] = grid[row-1][col];
    }
}
```

`System.out.println(grid[row][col] + "... " + row + ", " + col);` outputs: Why isn't column incrementing?

```
null... 9, 0
null... 8, 0
null... 7, 0
null... 6, 0
null... 5, 0
null... 4, 0
null... 3, 0
null... 2, 0
null... 1, 0
null... 0, 0
```

Comment: What's the current output? Are you sure you want to start at `row = grid.length -2` and not `row = grid.length - 1`?

Comment: Put a System.out.println after the invocation of the first for loop that displays the value for row.

Comment: @bakoyaro `grid = new Tile[width][height];`  Tile is just a class whose width and height are determined in Board.java - while filling the rows with paintComponent, I fill each tile as such: `g.fillRect(row * tilesize, col * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize);`

Comment: Your `columnsFilled` is set to zero outside of both loops and then is incremented while you're checking row by row and is never dropped back to zero again.  Was it your intention?

Comment: Your testing can be simplified by using a boolean, `isFull`, rather than an int. Initialize `isFull` to true before the second loop. set it to false on finding a null. Test as just `if(isFull)`.

Comment: @Growler see my answer posted below for an implementation that works

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan good point, Patricia. I've edited the code above.

Comment: Post the code that populates `grid`.  Presumably the column "isn't incrementing" because either a) you only have one column or b) the other columns are not null (you're only printing something if the column is null).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few problems here:

1. You should move `int columnsFilled = 0` inside the outer for loop since it's suppose to be a check of the current row only.  As it is now, after you get past the first row the count will be incorrect.
2. You are checking `if (columnsFilled == grid.length-1)` when in fact this should be `if (columnsFilled == grid[row].length-1)`.  Your check compares the number of filled columns against the number of rows, instead of against the number of columns in the given row.

Comment: I updated my post above. Still having issues with output. ANy thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might consider adding a convenience function similar to

```
public boolean isFullRow(Tile[][] grid, int row)
{
    for(int i=0; i<grid[row].length; i++)
    {
        if(grid[row][i] == null){ return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This would help debug your code, as well as make it (slightly but not noticeably) faster.

Then your `checkButtomFull()` function could look like

```
public void checkBottomFull() {
    //loops through rows only after each column has finished
    for(int row = grid.length-2; row > 0; row--) {
        if(isFullRow(grid, row)){
            // Do something if full row
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, as a minor point, my guess is that

```
for(int row = grid.length-2; row > 0; row--)
```

could/should be written as

```
for(int row = grid.length-1; row >= 0; row--) {
```

Comment: The two loop versions in your final point have very different effect. The rewrite cannot and should not be done if the OP intended to ignore the first and last rows.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, that's true.  If the intent was to ignore the first and last rows then it was written correctly.  However, my guess was that was not their intent.

Comment: @jedwards I like your idea of separating out. It still does not seem to be iterating the columnns in a particular row correctly as I've filled a row with all non-null values, yet isFull doesn't return true.

Comment: @Growler If isFull isn't returning true, then one of the cells is `== null`.  Consider adding a `println` in there to find out which one, then backtrack to find out why

Comment: So you're definitely getting `null`s.  My guess is that while you think you've filled a row with non null values, you're not doing it correctly.  Or you're doing it for a different row than the one you're testing.

Comment: @jedwards I've updated above. Column doesn't seem to be incrementing for some reason, but row is... that's why they're nulls. Not sure why column isn't incrementing though

Answer (score 1):

There were a few logic errors in the code you posted, the attached code fixes them without implementing everything for you.

```
public class SampleClass {

static String[][] grid = new String[4][10];

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    loadGrid();
    checkBottomFull();
}
public static void checkBottomFull() {
    int columnsFilled = 0;
    //loops through rows only after each column has finished
    for(int row = grid.length-1; row >= 0; row--) {//needed 'greater than or equal to'
        columnsFilled=0; //need to reinitialize this before every iteration
        for(int col = 0; col <= grid[row].length-1; col++) { //needed 'less than or equal to'
           System.out.println(row + ", " + col+", "+grid[row][col]);       
            if (grid[row][col] != null) {
                columnsFilled++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("columns that have a character" + columnsFilled);
        System.out.println("Needs to be "+grid[row].length+" to remove row");
        if (columnsFilled == grid[row].length) {
            System.out.println("full");   //this is where you should remove a row  
        }
    }
}

private static void loadGrid() {
    grid[0] = new String[] {"X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X"};
    grid[1] = new String[] {"X","X",null,"X","X","X",null,"X","X","X"};
    grid[2] = new String[] {"X","X","X",null,"X","X",null,"X","X","X"};
    grid[3] = new String[] {"X","X",null,"X","X","X",null,"X","X","X"};
}
```

}

Comment: @Growler Please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void checkBottomFull() {

    //loops through rows only after each column has finished
    for(int row = grid.length-1; row >= 0; row--) {
        //loops through all columns per row, then row decrements
        int columnsFilled = 0;
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.println(grid[row][col] + ", " + row + ", " + col);       
            if (grid[row][col] != null && ++columnsFilled == grid[row].length) {
                System.out.println("full");     
            }
        }
    }
}
```